# vector element operations in excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to perform the following in one steps (one formula):

Strip a letter from a column of elements and add them up.

Example:

Data:

1x
2y
3x

I want to strip letters and add up numbers all in one formula.

I understand that I could have a helper column in which I strip letters x,y,z and then have a formula to add up the numbers, but I don't want to do this.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Could you please elaborate... how does "vector" figure in to your question? What is the expected result? What have you tried?

Comment: I have a vector of such numbers, 1x, 2y 3x 4a 5b 6c....etc

Comment: Are your vectors always numeric-alpha?  Are the numbers always 0-9, or can they be larger?  Are they always in the same cell?, or are they in different cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming one entry per cell:

Is there only one letter at the end?  If so, you can use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--LEFT(A1:A100,LEN(A1:A100)-1))
```

If there might be multiple letters at the end, a simple UDF would be simpler:

```
Option Explicit
Function AddStrings(rg As Range)
    Dim L As Long
    Dim I As Long

For I = 1 To rg.Count
    L = L + Val(rg(I))
Next I

AddStrings = L
End Function
```

**EDIT:**  If some of the cells might be blank, you can use either the UDF, or, if you prefer the formula, this **array-entered** formula:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(--LEFT(A1:A100,LEN(A1:A100)-1),0))
```

To **array-enter** a formula, after entering
the formula into the cell or formula bar, hold down
**ctrl-shift** while hitting **enter**.  If you did this
correctly, Excel will place braces {...} around the formula.

Comment: Or just =SUMPRODUCT(1*LEFT(A1:A100)) and will work even with more letters in the end

Comment: @CRondao But not with more than one number at the beginning.

Comment: I like Ron Rosenfeld's response. What if one of the cells is empty? How can ignore it? Right now, I get #VALUE if at least one of the selected cells does not yield a number after truncation.

Comment: @user3376969 With cells in the range that do not include a number (or are empty), you can use the UDF.  You can also use an array formula -- I have edited my answer to show that.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you, Ron!

Comment: @CRondao Thank you for repeating the 2nd line of my answer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the format is consistent, you can do something like

```
=VALUE(LEFT(A1,1))+VALUE(MID(A1,4,1))+VALUE(MID(A1,7,1))
```

If the format is not consistent, things get more difficult. Let me know and I will expand the answer.

EDIT:

This function works with a variable length text, assuming that the fields are separated by the spaces and have one letter after the number:

```
Function AddValues(Text As String)
  Dim Tokens() As String, I As Integer
  Tokens = Split(Text)
  For I = 0 To UBound(Tokens)
    AddValues = AddValues + Val(Left(Tokens(I), Len(Tokens(I)) - 1))
  Next I
End Function
```

Comment: Supposed I have a whole bunch of values, say 100. I don't think this method would be efficient.